# Storing models which I'm unable to alter in EF Core

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I'm consuming an API which has a bunch of models which I'm using. Some of the models are quite large and I'm having troubles getting my database to migrate. The Entitys which I'm looking to store are shown here; https://www.lucidchart.com/documents/view/04c6d73b-961d-4d9f-b8dd-104dd9db8c94/0.

Each top level object is the one I control, which I'm storing the Primary Key in, and the containing objects are out of my control in terms of editing the actual files themselves, I've managed to get the first Table to work (SummonerTable) but am struggling to get the MatchReferenceTable to migrate correctly. I'm getting the error

```
The entity type 'MatchReference' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

When trying to add my migration.

All of the code I've done around the MatchReferenceTable is as follows;

Data object to store as per the entity diagram;

```
public class MatchReferenceDto
{
    public MatchReferenceDto() { }
    public MatchReferenceDto(MatchReference matchReference)
    {
        MatchReference = matchReference;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MatchReference MatchReference { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext class for this;

```
public class MatchReferenceDtoContext : DbContext
{
    public MatchReferenceDtoContext(DbContextOptions<MatchReferenceDtoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<MatchReferenceDto> MatchReferences { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MatchReferenceDto>().HasKey(c => c.Id);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And my services in startup.cs

This Database works and is active, I'll include my configurations similar to above for this in case I'm also doing something wrong here and have it working by chance.

```
var summonerConnection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=SummonerDb;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
services.AddDbContext<SummonerDtoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(summonerConnection));
```

My MatchReference service connection

```
var matchReferenceConnection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MatchReferenceDb;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
services.AddDbContext<MatchReferenceDtoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(matchReferenceConnection));
```

These are all of the configurations I've put in, and when trying to Add my migration I'm getting the error mentione above.

As mentioned above here are my configurations for the SummonerDtoConext;

Data object;

```
public class SummonerDto
{
    public SummonerDto()  {}
    public SummonerDto(Summoner summoner)
    {
        Summoner = summoner;
    }

    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateLastUpdated { get; set; }
    public Summoner Summoner { get; set; }
}
```

A note here, I've also tried the DatabaseGeneratedAttribute in my MatchReference data object.

DbContext;

```
public class SummonerDtoContext : DbContext
{
    public SummonerDtoContext(DbContextOptions<SummonerDtoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<SummonerDto> Summoners { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SummonerDto>().HasKey(c => c.Id);

        //Stop keys being generated automatically
        modelBuilder.Entity<Summoner>().Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Summoner>().Property(x => x.ProfileIconId).ValueGeneratedNever();
        modelBuilder.Entity<SummonerBase>().Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
        modelBuilder.Entity<SummonerBase>().Property(x => x.AccountId).ValueGeneratedNever();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And the server connection;

```
var summonerConnection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=SummonerDb;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
services.AddDbContext<SummonerDtoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(summonerConnection));
```

I'm trying to do everything I can to avoid duplicating the models supplied by the API that I'm using but I'm at a loss now on how to do what I'm looking at/if it's possible.

Comment: The exception message is pretty clear.  'MatchReference' doesn't have a primary key, at least not one EF knows about. But maybe you should look at [owned types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities).

Comment: @GertArnold That looks like what I'm after, I'll give it a try and report back.